# Android HttpUrlConnection how to read response into pieces

Tags: java, android, response, httpurlconnection

actually I need a little more information about how to read response from `HttpUrlConnection` class in Android SDK. I'm trying to read a response from web server,but when it's too big my applications is throwin an `OutOfMemoryException`.  So any source/help/suggestions on how to read the whole response into pieces is welcomed.

As I made a research I found out that I should set something like this : `((HttpURLConnection) connection).setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);` But my problem is that I don't know how to read this chuncked stream. So I'll be very happy if someone can guide me through the right way.

Thanks!

Sample Code :

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String deviceId = tm.getDeviceId();
            Log.w("device_identificator","device_identificator : "+deviceId);
            String resolution = Integer.toString(getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth())+ "x" +
                                         Integer.toString(getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
            Log.w("device_resolution","device_resolution : "+resolution);
            String version = "Android " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
            Log.w("device_os_type","device_os_type : "+version);
            Log.w("device_identification_string","device_identification_string : "+version);
            String locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString();
            Log.w("set_locale","set_locale : "+locale);
            String clientApiVersion = null;

            PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
            PackageInfo packageInfo;

            packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);

            clientApiVersion = packageInfo.versionName;
            Log.w("client_api_ver","client_api_ver : "+clientApiVersion);

            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
            String timeStamp = Long.toString(timestamp);


            String url = "http://www.rpc.shutdown.com";
            String charset = "UTF-8";
            String usernameHash = hashUser(username,password);
            String passwordHash = hashPass(username,password);


            String query = String.format("username_hash=%s&password_hash=%s&new_auth_data=%s&debug_data=%s&client_api_ver=%s&set_locale=%s&timestamp=%s&"+
                     "device_os_type=%s&mobile_imei=%s&device_sync_type=%s&device_identification_string=%s&device_identificator=%s&device_resolution=%s", 
                     URLEncoder.encode(usernameHash, charset), 
                     URLEncoder.encode(passwordHash, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode("1", charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode("1", charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode(clientApiVersion, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode(locale, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode(timeStamp, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode(version, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode(deviceId, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode("14", charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode(version, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode(deviceId, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode(resolution, charset));

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", charset);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
            OutputStream output = null;
            try {
                 output = connection.getOutputStream();
                 output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                 if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
            }

            int status = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
            Log.i("","Status : "+status);

            for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
                Log.i("Headers","Headers : "+header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());
            }

            InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
            Log.i("","Response : "+response.toString());
            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8*1024];
            while ((bytesRead = response.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
              String line = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
              Log.i("","line : "+line);
              handleDataFromSync(buffer);
            }
```

Comment: Could you post some sample code. It makes it easier to explain what to do in your specific situation.

Comment: I just added the code which I am using to send the params and connect to server and actually showing the response body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply allocate a byte buffer that can hold a small amount of data and read from the input stream into this buffer (using the [read](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) method). Something like:

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

int bytesRead = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
  // process the buffer, "bytesRead" have been read, no more, no less
}
```

Comment: That code is throwin me a `FileNotFoundException` on that line : `InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe the URL you provide is not correct (try it in a browser). Also, the code you pasted does not read from the URL but writes to it (sends data to the server and does not receive any). My code reads the response from the server.

Comment: yeah, actually i have to post some data and then to read the response from the server depending on the data I send.

Comment: I just edited my code and I can tell that I'm not receiving the whole inputstream.I receive only 8*1024 and than nothing.

Comment: This code works, check that an Exception does not get thrown, that would break the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

To read the Response Header try to use :

```
String sHeaderValue = connection.getHeaderField("Your_Header_Key");
```